# joining 3 tables with sum total from two columns meeting a certain criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have 3 tables:

```
Players
+------+-------+
| id   | name  |
+------+-------+
| 1    | Ben   |
| 2    | Bill  |
| 3    | John  |
| 4    | Hugh  |
| 5    | Fred  |
+------|-------+
```

```
     Game1              Game2
+------+-------+    +------+-------+
| p_id | points|    | p_id | points| 
+------+-------+    +------+-------+
| 1    | 800   |    | 1    | 300   |
| 1    | 400   |    | 5    | 800   |
| 2    | 100   |    | 2    | 900   |
| 3    | 1000  |    | 4    | 1200  |
+------|-------+    +------|-------+
```

I want to sum the total of points from both tables, grouped by p_ID where the sum is greater than a certain amount, 1000 for example. So i would want the result to look like this.

```
Query Result
+------+---------+---------+--------+
| p_id | points1 | points2 | total  |
+------+---------+---------+--------+
| 1    |  1200   |   300   |  1500  |
| 2    |  100    |   900   |  1000  |
| 3    |  1000   |    0    |  1000  |
| 4    |   0     |   1200  |  1200  |
+------|---------+---------+--------+
```

Below is my current query but I'm not getting the results I need.

```
SELECT `players`.`p_id`, 
COALESCE(sum(`Game1`.`points`), 0) as 'Game1', 
COALESCE(sum(`Game2`.`points`), 0) as 'Game_2', 
COALESCE(sum(`Game1`.`points`), 0) + COALESCE(sum(`Game2`.`points`), 0) as 'total' 
from `players` 
left join `Game1` on `players`.`p_id`=`Game1`.`p_id` 
left join `Game2` on `players`.`p_id`=`Game2`.`p_id` 
having sum(`Game2`.`points`) + sum(`Game1`.`points`) >= 1000 
order by sum(`Game1`.`points`) + 
sum(`Game2`.`points`) desc
```

Comment: Did you just forget to `GROUP BY players.p_id`? (MySQL allows you to omit it, often with unexpected results many other RDBMS would just error)

Comment: Does that not sound like a having clause ?

Answer (score 2):

In order for this to work correctly, you need to do the aggregation *before* the join.  Otherwise, you end up with issues related to a cartesian product for each game.

Because MySQL does not support `full outer join`, the best way is to use `union all` instead:

```
select p_id, sum(points1) as points1, sum(points2) as points2
from ((select p_id, points as points1, 0 as points2
       from Game1
      ) union all
      (select p_id, 0, points
       from Game2
      )
     ) g
group by p_id;
```

Comment: Gordon, I do not really understand that argument: Trying out in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0992/1 does not show this ... could you elaborate? I think this is something, I would really want to fully understand,

Comment: Forget it ... I understood now!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  players.id AS p_id,
  IFNULL(points1,0) AS Game1,
  IFNULL(points2,0) AS Game2,
  IFNULL(points1,0)+IFNULL(points2,0) AS total
FROM players
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT p_id, SUM(Game1.points) AS points1
    FROM Game1
    GROUP BY p_id
  ) AS GameSum1 ON players.id=GameSum1.p_id
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT p_id, SUM(Game2.points) AS points2
    FROM Game2
    GROUP BY p_id
  ) AS GameSum2 ON players.id=GameSum2.p_id
GROUP BY players.id
HAVING total>=1000
ORDER BY total DESC
```

**EDIT**

Fixed wrong `IFNULL()` scope, see [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0992/1)

**EDIT 2**

Fixed according to @GordonLinoff's input

Comment: Note that COALESCE conforms to the standard

Comment: Noted. Now note, that `IFNULL()` works identical in MySQL and is much more readable (not overloaded). `IF()` and `CASE WHEN` would work as well. De gustibus non est disbutantur.

Comment: It is more flexible for **other cases**, which don't apply here. Again: Tastes differ.

Comment: Sic transit gloria mundi

Comment: You lost me, but I do not think, I lost something by that.

Comment: Thanks for the post Eugene. However, the result I get for ID # is 1800 when it should be 1500. I guess this is because game2 is getting added twice (once for each row in game1)